# Protractor console logs when run with directConnect:True

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, test-configration

When the config file is executed with directConnect:True flag, I am getting console logs that show more errors about my angular application.

[image]

When directconnect flag is removed, there are no warning messages printed on the console.

[image]

Could someone help me to figure out why this behaviour?

**Note:**

The console errors where actual bugs with the angular page and dev is fixing it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`directConnet=true` bypasses SeleniumServer and execute against `Chrome driver` and `Firefox driver`.
If you are using other than chrome or firefox browser, you will get an error. Refer this:
http://www.protractortest.org/#/server-setup#connecting-directly-to-browser-drivers